# Cannot post activity. Unauthorized. 401 bot framework emulator

Tags: botframework, botframeworkemulator

I have been facing this issue randomly(sometimes the bot responds / sometime not), when I try to test by bot in emulator. I have no app id/password pasted in appsettings.json and in emulator, but still I get "UnAuthorized" error.

[image]

The Bot runs fine on publishing to azure, I just add my Appid/AppPassword while publishing, but would remove that once I am debugging it locally.

I am on my home network and there isn't any issue with other bots. I have updated to .NET core 3.1 with bot builder SDK 4.9.

[image]

Comment: what version of the emulator are you on? Does the port-number match the port number shown in the browser where your application is running?

Comment: I am on emulator v4.9 and yes, it matches both ways.

Comment: not sure what might be causing this issue as your other bots are working as expected. Is this on a Mac by any chance? I would suggest opening an issue on https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/issues if the issue is not intermittent.

Comment: I just deleted the entries and headings for both app id/Password and re-wrote it again manually but didn't provide any value, and it just works :/